# Integer solution of $x^8-24x^7-18x^5+39x^2+1155=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The number of Integral Roots of the equation
>   $x^8-24x^7-18x^5+39x^2+1155=0$

My Try: Using integral roots Theorem, integer solution of this equation is all possible factor of $1155 = \pm 3 \times \pm 5 \times \pm 7 \times \pm 11$. Now how can I calculate after that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term $a_1x$ is missing from the polynomial $f(x)=x^8-24x^7-18x^5+39x^2+1155$ and $1155$ is a squarefree integer; therefore (since $\pm1$ are not solutions) the equation  $f(x)=0$ does not have integer solutions.
For, if $r\in\mathbb Z$ is a solution then $$r^8-24r^7-18r^5+39r^2+1155=0\Rightarrow r^2(r^6-24r^5-18r^3+39)=-1155\Rightarrow r^2\mid1155.$$

More generally if $a_0\in\mathbb Z$ is not divided by a $k^{th}$ power of any prime number, then the only possible integer solutions of the equation $$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_kx^k+a_0=0$$ are $\pm1$.

Comment: can you please explain "More generally if $a_0\in\mathbb N$ is not divided by a $k^{th}$ power of any prime number, the equation $$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_kx^k+a_0=0$$ does not have integer solutions." more in-depth? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @gekkostate I made a correction. The only possible solutions are $\pm1$. This is because $$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_kx^k+a_0=0\iff x^k(a_nx^{n-k}+a_{n-1}x^{n-k-1}+\ldots+a_k)=-a_0$$ so if $r\neq\pm1$ is a solution, $r^k\mid a_0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Try Eisenstein's criterion.